# Error linking RShiny forms to SQLite database

Tags: r, sqlite

I'm trying to link data entered into a Shiny form to SQLite. The Shiny part works just fine as I've tried saving the data to an excel file. When I try to write the data to SQLite, I keep getting this error "Near "delete": syntax error" -- any ideas on what it could possible be? I've also tried this with just three input variables and it writes it just fine to SQLite but with ~20 variables, I keep getting this error.

Comment: We can't possibly help without seeing the code.

Comment: @r2evans thanks! I just figured out that one of my variables "delete" was causing an issue.

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem. I suggest you should either delete the question or [edit] it to make it reproducible enough, then self-answer. Either way, leaving it in its current form is not encouraged. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your variables should be quoted when sending statements to SQLite. If your variable of interest is generated by an input you can quote it like this `paste0('"',input$variable,'"')`